# Setting custom colors for the Column chart Report type in SSRS

Tags: colors, bar-chart, palette, ssrs-2017

I have Column type SSRS 2017 report and would like to set a different **custom**, non standard colors for 2 of my values - "Current period", "Prior period" (it's green and grey now):
[image]

To achieve this I select **Chart Properties / Color Palette / Custom**
But when I select Custom, instead of current - Pacific Light, it displays white color (no color) on both of my bars.

Where do I go to modify Custom - to the color I want?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom Colors are set up in the Chart's Properties' `Custom Pallette Colors`.

[image]

You just add your colors.

[image]